# CSS file is not implementing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am designing this webpage. I am using bootstrap, html, css, jsp.
I want my styles to be inside in a `mystyles.css` file.

In my jsp I have this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/mystyles.css" />
```

Basically, It is just a link to my mystyles.css file.
This file just has basic css stuff, editing the margin, center etc.

```
.center_div {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 25%;
}

.top-buffer {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.img-space {
    margin: 20px;
}

.bdr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.longform {
    width: 350px;
}
```

When I try adding the class bdr to the div col, it is not working. But when I just add the style directly to my jsp, It is working.

Working:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">CITY ADDRESS: <input style="width:350px" type="text" /></div>

<div class="col-sm-4" style="border: 1px solid black" >LAST NAME: <input type="text" /></div>
```

Not working:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">CITY ADDRESS: <input class="longform" type="text" /></div>

<div class="col-sm-4" class="bdr" >LAST NAME: <input type="text" /></div>
```

But the other CSS styles I inputted are working, the center_div, top_buffer and etc.  The `mystyles.css` is also used by other pages.

Why is it working when I just put `"style:..."` rather than putting it to a `class="..."` and link it to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the class attribute twice

```
<div class="col-sm-4" class="bdr" >LAST NAME: <input type="text" /></div>
       ↑                ↑
```

it has to be like this, with a space between `col-sm-4` and `bdr`

```
<div class="col-sm-4 bdr" >LAST NAME: <input type="text" /></div>
```

Sample snippet

```css
.bdr {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" class="bdr" >LAST NAME: <input type="text" /></div>

<div class="col-sm-4 bdr" >LAST NAME: <input type="text" /></div>
```

---

Your code sample with my update, now both works, and if it doesn't in your own full code, you likely have another rule interfere with the `.bdr` rule.

*Also note [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) affect which rule will apply*

```css
.center_div {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 25%;
}

.top-buffer {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.img-space {
    margin: 20px;
}

.bdr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.longform {
    width: 350px;
}
```

```html
Working:<br><br>

<div class="col-sm-6">CITY ADDRESS: <input style="width:350px" type="text" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="border: 1px solid black" >LAST NAME: <input type="text" /></div>

<br><strike>Not</strike> working:<br><br>

<div class="col-sm-6">CITY ADDRESS: <input class="longform" type="text" /></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 bdr" >LAST NAME: <input type="text" /></div>
```

Comment: It is correct, but it is not the answer. I tried creating another css file and put only the `.border` in it. It worked. I dont know why though.

Comment: @guwop69 Check my update, it works, which likely mean you have another rule interfere with the `.bdr`

Answer (score 0):

Did yo check through inspected the element. Does it showing the class or not? If it is loading then border property from other class overrides the border of bdr.In this case you should give a try  to !important after border property. Like

```
.bdr{
   border:1px solid black !important;
}
```

It will work if your css file is loaded by jsp.

Comment: Finding the interfering rule is how to solve it, not using `!important`

Comment: In your jsp first load self_made_styles then others like  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/mystyles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 As browser loads styles from top to bottom . whichever property is loaded first or found first will be applied. Thnq .

Comment: **Wrong**, whichever rule found _last_ is loaded, and if `!important` is used, the last of those, even if a rule found later target the same element. Another thing that can interfere is [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Oh I made mistake loaded las or found last. thnx for correction. Didn't go through comment before posting .